# How to use quick measure MoM% and apply filter on visual to exclude current month

Tags: powerbi, dax

I used the quick measure MoM% from power Bi as such :

```
VAR __PREV_MONTH =
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE('DAUMAU'[MAU]),
        DATEADD('DAUMAU'[login_date], -1, MONTH)
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE(
        AVERAGE('DAUMAU'[MAU]) - __PREV_MONTH,
        __PREV_MONTH
    )
```

I am using a line stacked column chart and the data for this visual cannot load:

> Calculation error in measure ____: Function 'DATEADD' expects a
>   contiguous selection when the date column comes from a table on the
>   1-side of a bi-directional relationship.

I also need to make sure the current month is excluded in the visual. Should I modify my code or apply a filter? If its the latter, how can I use my date column to specify exclude current month. I tried adding it in the visual filter and looked at advanced, relative, and selective filtering but it wouldn't work without me manually changing it every month.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a calendar table. The time intelligence functions are designed to work with a contiguous date table.

Comment: so they created quick measures that can only work (at its optimal efficiency) if a manual calendar table is created?

Comment: If you have the Time intelligence > Auto Date/Time option turned on in Options > Data Load, then it tries to automatically create hidden date tables to use for time intelligence functions, but I usually prefer to manage the date tables myself.

Comment: i guess  i have no choice than to create a calendar table, mind writing that as an answer with maybe a link to creating it to accept it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the time intelligence functions to work properly, they require you to have a date table that is contiguous and contains a unique row for every day in the years in use.

You can create a minimal table in DAX using `CALENDAR` or `CALENDARAUTO` or you can use a template to create on in the query editor or as a calculated table.

Here's a reference to a template that probably has anything you'd ever need:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/reference-date-table-in-dax-and-power-bi/